# How to set INOUT parameters from frontend while calling a stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

I developed a SP, say abc(a,b,c), where

- a is IN parameter
- b is OUT parameter
- c is INOUT parameter.

If i call this sp directly from the DB as `abc(<val>,?,?),` I get err

`The number of variables in the EXECUTE statement, the number of variables in the OPEN statement, or the number of arguments in an OPEN statement for a parameterized cursor is not equal to the number of values required.`

But if i run it as `abc(<val>,?,<val>)`, it runs successfully.

I want to call this SP through Java program. For this, i am setting IN & INOUT parameters. And registering OUT & INOUT parameters. But it is giving me the same error as above

Answer (score 6):

Pl read [CallableStatements and INOUT Parameters](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefjdbc75719.html)

Comment: i know this is a late reply., but ppl who visit this page will get a better understanding

Comment: It's a long time I posted this question. Now I dint even remember the original context of asking this question. Let me brush my memories. :)

Comment: This helped me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`java.sql.CallableStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) to process out parameters.

So, following your example, your call would be:

```
String sql = "{ call abc(?, ?, ?) }";
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);
cs.setInt(1, 20); // setting "a" in parameter to 1
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR); // setting "b" as out parameter
cs.setString(3, "Some String"); // setting "c" as in parameter
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR); // setting "c" as out parameter
// then execute
cs.executeUpdate();
// and retrieve out parameters
String bout = cs.getString(2);
String cout = cs.getString(3);
```

Comment: definetly i am using callablestatement. Without this, i dont know another way to call SP. My question is HOW TO SET INOUT parameters?

Comment: @articlestack: If you are already using CallableStatement, then just read the documentation on it and make it run.

Comment: I was doing in the same way as it is suggested. And i am facing following err "The number of variables in the EXECUTE statement, the number of variables in the OPEN statement, or the number of arguments in an OPEN statement for a parameterized cursor is not equal to the number of values required."

Comment: Then you probably need to specify what's your procedure code in order to get proper help. By the title, people might think that you don't know how to get out parameters from stored procedures in JDBC. When clearly your problem is not on JDBC side but on the stored proc side.